# How to set framebuffer's output?

Tags: linux, graphics, framebuffer

I'm using linux (4.4) and Nvidia proprietary driver (361). A also have two monitors (one VGA, one HDMI). By default (during BIOS stage of booting) the image is displayed only on VGA output. After BIOS is done grub's output and VT0's output (/dev/tty0) are displayed on VGA output only too. How can I redirect output to HDMI or redirect to both?

With open source driver (nouveau) the output is displayed o both screens.